# Executing command with parameters without shell in php

Tags: php, shell

Is there a way in php to execute a command with arguments but without having "shell".

The problem is that both `exec()` and `shell_exec()` runs the supplied string in a shell and therefor any user inputted data must be escaped.

Is there a way to do it like:

```
some_exec(["command","argument","argument])
```

As one would do it in for example Python or Java.

I would very much be able to execute commands with arguments without having to escape some of the arguments.

I'm working on a UI for a router and the Wifi key is set trough a command
and right now I have to escape the string which limits the number of characters that the key can contain. If i where not to escape the key one could do injections without any problems.

***Clarification***
The reason why this actually is an annoying problem in this case is that i need to execute the following command:

```
wireless.@wifi-iface[0].key='<the password>'
```

The problem is that since the password is being set in a string this password , `$il|\|t` would become `\$ile\|\\\|t` and the problem now is that incorrect password is a valid one. And so the password that was stored is not the same as the user entered.

And even though we enter the password in a string we can still do an inject like this `' ; reboot ; '`

Comment: Just check with the below link  [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php[/link]

Answer (score 0):

I have some trouble understanding your need not to escape arguments. I tried to call echo with an escaped string, and echo displays the original string :

```
$cmd = 'echo';
$passwd = escapeshellarg('&#;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$');
echo 'ARG : ' . $passwd . PHP_EOL;

exec($cmd . ' ' . $passwd, $output);
echo 'exec : ' . $output[0] . PHP_EOL;

echo 'passthru : ';
passthru($cmd . ' ' . $passwd);

echo 'shell_exec : ' . shell_exec($cmd . ' ' . $passwd);

echo 'system : ';
system($cmd . ' ' . $passwd);
```

Here is the output :

```
ARG : '&#;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$'
exec : &#;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$
passthru : &#;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$
shell_exec : &#;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$
system : &#;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$
```

Could you give an example of the command you want to execute ?

Comment: i need to execute this:
`uci set wireless.radio[0]='<the password>'`. If Say the user wants the password `$ile|\|t"` this would be escaped into: `\$ile\|\\\|t` The problem is that since its in a string the password gets set as it is. but i can still do an injection by providing a password that is `' ; reboot ; '`

Comment: $cmd = 'uci set wireless.radio[0]=';
$passwd = escapeshellarg('$ile|\|t"');

$fullCommand = $cmd.$passwd;

provides the following output : uci set wireless.radio[0]='$ile|\|t"' which seems ok